# Error when taking a screenshot in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to take a screenshot by using the following code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://10.4.16.159/");
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\test\\screenshot.JPG"));
```

But I'm not able to take the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to save screenshot to another disk partition, etc d:

```
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("d:\\screenshot.JPG"));
```

. It seems like app just does not have permission to drive c: